# VueJS: Possible to set v- directives within a directive, defined in a module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a master checkbox mixin, which manages the state of a masterCheckbox, and followerCheckboxes. Instead of having to set directives like v-model several times on different checkbox elements, it would be alot nicer to set one directive which takes care of that.

The example below is not working, and instead I have to set these individually on the component that uses the mixin. Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not possible?

```
// define a mixin object
module.exports = {
    directives: {
        masterCheckbox: {
            // directive definition
            bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
                el.setAttribute("v-on:click", "toggleMasterCheckbox");
                el.setAttribute("v-model", "masterCheckboxChecked");
                el.setAttribute(":indeterminate.prop", "masterCheckboxIndeterminate");
            }
        },
        followerCheckbox: {
            // directive definition
            bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
                el.setAttribute("v-model", "checkedCheckboxes");
            }
        }
    },

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directives are not attributes, they are non-HTML markup in the template that Vue processes away before creating HTML. You're setting attributes on DOM elements well after Vue has created them from template. So what you are trying to do cannot be done.

You should probably set up a component – possibly a dynamic component – in whose template you can include all the appropriate directives, and then use multiple places. But I think your `click` and `v-model` directives are going to fight, as `v-model` is going to change the value of `masterCheckboxChecked`, and so is `toggleMasterCheckbox`.